# Gradually Increasing Circles CSS, HTML and Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I added a legend / Key in the map  which is alright in case of squares but in circles, they are not aligned with the text, is there any way to align the text and the circles properly.
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KodTF.png)

Here is the code

```
function getsizeLabel(d)
{
      return d > 90 ?  18 :
             d > 60 ?  14 :
             d > 30 ?  9 :
                       5 ;
}

function AddLDLegend() {
 legendLD = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
 legendLD.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        labels = ['<strong>Lockdown Days</strong>'],
        grades = [0, 30, 60, 90],
        categories = ['1-30','31-60','61-90'];

    for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
        labels.push(
      '<i style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid #8A2BE2; width:' + getsizeLabel(grades[i] + 1) +'px; height:' +  getsizeLabel(grades[i] + 1) +'px;"></i> ' +
       (grades[i] + grades[i+1]  ? categories[i] : '91-100'));
          } 
          div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
          return div;
   };
  legendLD.addTo(map);
  }
```

The `map` is leaflet map I am just calling this function to add legend from another function but the design and everything related to the small legend div is in this function.

the preference for the text and circle alignment is in this image

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4u2h1.png)

Comment: Where do you want a circle to be relative to its text? e.g. with center of circle on baseline or bottom of circle on baseline or...

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, to answer your question I have edited my question and added another image at the end.

Comment: Any particular typeface? And also font size? Different type faces will have differing heights for the same font size. The alignment will probably be a bit approximate, but it may not matter in practice, we’ll see.

Comment: For the time being I am using this
   ( font: 14px/16px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;)
But if they are aligned any sans serif will work with 10-16 size

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I think the answer from @ErnestoStifano is pretty good for Ariel on the browsers I've tried. For a serif font it can look a bit misaligned (even though technically it isn't). I think because my eye felt the hyphen should be aligned with the center of the circle - it sort of dominates more than say the horizontal of an 'e' (as in your image).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you was trying to achieve. Please let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
const grades = [0, 30, 60, 90];
const categories = ['1-30', '31-60', '61-90'];

function getSize(g) {
  return (
    g > 90 ?  18 :
    g > 60 ?  14 :
    g > 30 ?  9 : 5
  );
}

function getLabel(i) {
  const size = getSize(grades[i] + 1);
  const grade = (grades[i] + grades[i + 1] ? categories[i] : '91-100');
  
  const bulletStyle = [
    'display: inline-block;',
    'vertical-align: middle;',
    'border-radius: 50%;',
    'border: 1px solid #8A2BE2;',
    `height: ${size}px;`,
    `width: ${size}px;`
  ];
  
  const valueStyle = [
    'display: inline-block;',
    'vertical-align: middle;'
  ];
  
  const bullet = `<i style="${bulletStyle.join(' ')}"></i>`;
  
  const value = `<span style="${valueStyle.join(' ')}">${grade}</span>`

  return  bullet + ' ' + value;
}

function getDiv() {
  const div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
  const labels = ['<strong>Lockdown Days</strong>'];

  for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
    div.innerHTML += labels.push(getLabel(i));
  }
    
  div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');

  return div;
};

document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].appendChild(getDiv());
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort, I really appreciate it. But as I mentioned earlier I am adding a legend on a Webmap and I am also not an expert. using this method I am not able to add the legend my complete function was adding the Map legend like this

I apologize for the bad formatting

Comment: `legendLD = L.control({position: 'bottomright'});
 legendLD.onAdd = function (map) {
    var div = L.DomUtil.create('div', 'info legend');
        labels = ['<strong>Lockdown Days</strong>'],
        grades = [0, 30, 60, 90],
        categories = ['1-30','31-60','61-90'];`

Comment: `for (var i = 0; i < grades.length; i++) {
        div.innerHTML +=
        labels.push(
      '<i style="border-radius: 50%; border: 1px solid #8A2BE2; width:' + getsizeLabel(grades[i] + 1) +'px; height:' +  getsizeLabel(grades[i] + 1) +'px;"></i> ' +
       (grades[i] + grades[i+1]  ? categories[i] : '91-100'));
          } 
          div.innerHTML = labels.join('<br>');
          return div;
   };
  legendLD.addTo(map);`

Comment: @HassamAli can't you just do `legendLD.onAdd = getDiv`?

Comment: In that case it adds the legend but without the formatting and secondly console shows the error 
`getDiv is not defined`
at the last line

Comment: @HassamAli could you please update your question to see the full code, so I can understand better what you are trying to do. If not, I will not be able to help.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time and effort. I have added the whole function and if you need more please let me know.